# VBA Inserting Cell with Browsing File

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub selectFile()

'Create and set dialog box as variable
Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

'Do not allow multiple files to be selected
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False

'Set the title of of the DialogBox
dialogBox.Title = "Select a file"

'Set the default folder to open
dialogBox.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Downloads"

'Clear the dialog box filters
dialogBox.Filters.Clear


'Show the dialog box and output full file name
If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("filePath").Value = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
End If

End Sub
```

I am trying select different file for different cell. I try range, but it still only allow me to select one file for the all the cell in that range. Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance. This code is from https://exceloffthegrid.com/insert-file-path-into-cell-with-browse-button/

Thanks Tim for reminding me to put up the source. I am not very familiar with the posting policy. Sorry about that

Comment: "I am trying insert this vba into a row" this statement doesn't really make sense. You may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71743037/edit) to clarify what it is you want to achieve

Comment: Seems like this code is straight from here - https://exceloffthegrid.com/insert-file-path-into-cell-with-browse-button/   When posting code you didn't write, it's useful to let us know that (and polite to attribute it to the source) so we can give suggestions that are more likely to be helpful to you (instead of thinking "if they wrote this already then why is it not doing what they want?")